# Using re to return sentences as a list containing a specific word

Tags: python

Use re to return sentences containing specific word from a huge string.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem.

```py
def find_sentences_with_keyword(text, keyword):

    splitter = text.split(". ")


the outputs:
string = Just on the report itself, I think people would want to sell the market. However, the fact that it really makes the case for a rate cut, I think is why you're seeing the market hang in there,' said JJ Kinahan, chief market strategist at TD Ameritrade. Market expectations for a Fed rate cut in June rose to 27.5% from 16.7% after the data release, according to the CME Group's FedWatchtool. The market is also pricing in a 79% chance of lower Fed rates by August.

find_sentences_with_keyword("market", string) = ["Just on the report itself, I think people would want to sell the market.", "However, the fact that it really makes the case for a rate cut, I think is why you're seeing the market hang in there,' said JJ Kinahan, chief market strategist at TD Ameritrade.", "Market expectations for a Fed rate cut in June rose to 27.5% from 16.7% after the data release, according to the CME Group's FedWatchtool.", "The market is also pricing in a 79% chance of lower Fed rates by August."]

find_sentences_with_keyword("Market", string) = ["Market expectations for a Fed rate cut in June rose to 27.5% from 16.7% after the data release, according to the CME Group's FedWatchtool."]
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. It also seems that you are passing arguments to your function in the wrong order.

Comment: after splitter, i'd like to use regex to get those outputs

Answer (score 2):

How about this (case-sensitive):

```
def find_sentences_with_keyword(text, keyword):
    splitter = text.split(". ")
    return [x for x in splitter if keyword in x]
```

The same for case-insensitive:

```
def find_sentences_with_keyword(text, keyword):
    splitter = text.split(". ")
    return [x for x in splitter if keyword.lower() in x.lower()]
```

Comment: it does work. but for keyword "august" it does not return the sentence with August. but i'd also like to know how to do it with regex

Comment: I was just testing the same thing. It works good, but unfortunately it also splits the numbers `27.5%` and `16.7%`. I guess some better way of splitting the string into separate sentences needs to be implemented

Comment: @IniyanSurendran From your example I understood that you want to have case-sensitive matching (market vs Market), anyway I've added the case-insensitive code as well. For regex code I'd suggest to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999064/regex-for-string-contains @Irek I believe you split by `"."` instead of `". "`. Because split with `". "` cannot and will not ever split the examples you've posted.

Comment: but for keyword "august" it returns an empty list.

Comment: Not for me: `>>> find_sentences_with_keyword(test, "August")
['The market is also pricing in a 79% chance of lower Fed rates by August.']
>>> find_sentences_with_keyword(test, "august")
['The market is also pricing in a 79% chance of lower Fed rates by August.']`, works as expected, make sure to execute the second version (case-insensitive).