# How to find specific strings in a file?

Tags: python

This is a script that I have written to find all the lines with usb in it. However, the problem is that if also returns lines if they have words such as usbcore as well. I am interested in lines that contain only the words usb.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

logFile = open(sys.argv[1])

print("Printing all lines with USB in it...")

for line in logFile.readlines():
    if line.lower().find('usb') != -1:
        print(line)

print('Done!')
```

Comment: Depending on your concrete criterion, search for e.g. ' usb ' instead.

Comment: you should use regex as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999064/regex-for-string-contains).

Comment: ctenar and what if the word is at the beginning of the sentence and there is no space before it? Regex would be a better approach in my opinion

Comment: You can use a regex for condition `if re.search(r'\busb\b', line, re.I):
      print(line)`.  This finds usb, case insensitive. `\b` means must be surrounded by border such as beginning of line, space or end of line.

Comment: You can check my answer , it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the word `' usb '` with spaces :

```
import sys

logFile = open(sys.argv[1])

print("Printing all lines with USB in it...")

for line in logFile.readlines():
    if line.lower().find(' usb ') != -1:
        print(line)

print('Done!')
```

- Example :

  ```
  a = ' i have usbbox '
  b = ' i have usb '
  a.find('usb') # != -1
  a.find(' usb ') # = -1 , bcs it doesnt contain the word 'usb' only
  b.find(' usb ') # != -1 , it contains it
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a one-liner:

```
with open(sys.arg[1]) as f: 
    print(''.join([l for l in f.readlines() if ' ubs ' in l.lower()])
```