# How to implement a function that matches a specific paragraph in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

full url : abc.com/product/123

find url : abc.com/product

I want to return true if the full url contains find url

The condition must match the sentences of find url and the words in the full url perfectly.

```
fullurl.indexOf('abc') // this find true It is a condition that only certain words should not be split.
```

I want the result value

```
fullurl = 'abc.com/product/123'; 
findurl = 'abc.com/product';

fullurl.indexOf('abc'); // this find false 
fullurl.indexOf('pro'); // this find false 
fullurl.indexOf('abc.com'); // this find false 
fullurl.indexOf('abc.com/product'); // this true This result is the return value I want
```

I can't get the result I want with the indexOf function alone. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return true if **fullurl** contains **findurl**.

I used regex, if you want to change the **findurl** you need to edit the regex code.

```
function matchUrl(fullurl) {
  reg = /\babc.com\/product\b/;
  if (fullurl.match(reg)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Check this out to further understand the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999084/12194627) I used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply regarding the solution